# How do I find all the words until a certain word with regex?

Tags: regex

I have this body content below

```
[url=undefined][i][/i] John Doe wrote:[/url] Some other random wrote
[url=undefined][i][/i] John Doe Junior wrote:[/url] random stuff again
[url=undefined][i][/i] John Doe Junior III wrote:[/url] random stuff wrote
[url=undefined][i][/i] John wrote:[/url] random stuff wrote
```

I am trying to pull out the names `John Doe`, `John Doe Junior`, `John Doe Junior III` and `John` using regex. I have it almost working but I can't seem to get over the hump

My Regex fails when there is a single name

```
/undefined\]\[i\].\[\/i\].(\w+.+?)?.wrote/
```

Any ideas how I can get the matching groups, of any name before the wrote word and not greedy

My test URL is here https://regex101.com/r/pJPbvt/2

Comment: If you just use a global flag, your regex101 seems to work as desired? https://regex101.com/r/ElxQcX/1

Comment: What language/tool do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines ..

`\[/i\]\s*(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*?)\s*wrote:`

https://regex101.com/r/dGMd0b/1

```
 \[/i\]  
 \s* 
 (                             # (1 start)
      \S+ 
      (?: \s+ \S+ )*?
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s* wrote:
```

Comment: `undefined\]\[i\].\[\/i\]\s*(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*?)\s*wrote:`